# React setState callback won't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I have 3 functions below. One containing calls to the two (getBooks), which are getting requests. I set my state (isLoading) to true before the calls and then to true after the calls. This is to also make sure that the data is properly loaded. However the state is not updating so, therefore, my data from the get request is invalid. The callbacks in my setstate work in my other components, so I am confused. Below are my 3 functions.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SidePane from './SidePane.js';
import HomeNavBar from './HomeNavBar.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';
import Loading from './Loading.js';

class HomePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            bookSearch: "",
            bookSearchResults: [],
            bookSearchFound: false,
            isLoading: false
        };
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.alertBookName = this.alertBookName.bind(this);
        this.getBooksFromIsbn = this.getBooksFromIsbn.bind(this);
        this.getBooks = this.getBooks.bind(this);
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }

    changeBookName = (e) => {

        var bookName = e.target.value;
        bookName = bookName.split(' ').join('+');
        this.setState({bookSearch: bookName})
    }

    getBooksFromIsbn(isbns){

        var books = [];

        axios
            .get('http://localhost:9000/api/getBooksFromIsbn',
            {
                params: {
                    books: JSON.stringify(isbns)
                }
            })
            .then(res =>
            {
                console.log(res.data);
                books = res.data;


            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response);
            });
    }


    getBooks(){

        this.setState({
            isLoading: true
        },
            function(){console.log("setState completed", this.state)}
        );

        var bookResults = this.handleSearch();
        var books = this.getBooksFromIsbn(bookResults);

        this.setState({
            isLoading: false
        },
            function(){console.log("setState completed", this.state)}
        );
        this.props.setBookSearchResults(books);
    }


    handleSearch(){

        var bookResults = [];

        var url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/getOpenLibrarySearch';

        axios
        .get(url,
        {
            params: {
                bookSearch: this.state.bookSearch
            }
        })
        .then(res =>
        {
            //this.setState({bookSearchResults: res.data});

            for(var i=0; i < res.data.docs[i].isbn.length; i++){
                bookResults = bookResults.concat(res.data.docs[i].isbn);
            }
            console.log(bookResults);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response);
        });

        return bookResults;
    }

    render(){

        if(this.state.isLoading == false){
            return(
                <div>
                    <HomeNavBar authToken = {this.props.authToken} email = {this.props.email} />
                    <SidePane changeBookName = {this.changeBookName} handleSearch = {this.getBooks} />
                </div>
            )           
        }
        else
        {
            return <Loading />;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "However the state is not updating" — Why do you expect it to update when you "change" it from `true` to `true`?

Comment: Aside: `handleSearch` always returns an empty array and `getBooksFromIsbn` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please show the entire component, Need to know when getBooks is called.
Furthermore, if you can, please make working example in codesandbox.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I actually had both of them set to true just to see if it would change them because isLoading is defaulted to false. I updated my code above

Comment: @Quentin Could you give me some insight on how to not make them return as empty and undefined?

Comment: @EdwinClement Alright I updated my code above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to actually return the `books` value from `getBooksFromIsbn`. Await the axios call resolution and return `books`.

```
async getBooksFromIsbn (isbns) {
  const books = [];

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      'http://localhost:9000/api/getBooksFromIsbn',
      {
        params: {
          books: JSON.stringify(isbns)
        }
      });
    books = res.data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.response);
  }

  return books; 
}
```

Same for `handleSearch`, the code needs to wait and return the resolution of the GET request.

Comment: I changed the functions to async and awaited both calls to handleSearch and getBooksFromIsbn however the books returned ends up being undefined